# Словарь, где значениями выступают подсписки по их сумме

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, циклы, dict

У меня есть некий массив данных, который я забираю из экселевского файла и заворачиваю в список (1). Далее я пытаюсь сформировать словарь, где в качестве значений выступают подсписки, состоящие из первых элементов основного списка (1), сумма которых не больше 40. Ниже код:

```
def weeks_split(array):
    new_h_list = cp.copy(array)
    index = 1
    sub_list = []
    week_list = {}

    while new_h_list:        
        sub_list.append(new_h_list.pop(0))
        if sum(sub_list) >= 40:
            print(sub_list)
            week_list[index] = sub_list
            index += 1
            sub_list.clear()
            
    return week_list
```

Словарь по итогу формируется, но все значения у ключей одинаковые. Причём видно, что подсписки формируются так, как мне нужно, но в словарь залетает что-то непонятное)

```
[16, 8, 6, 0, 4, 0, 8]
[3, 3, 4, 34]
[10, 0, 6, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 0, 8]
[4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4]
[3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 0, 16, 6, 2, 6]
[8, 0, 10, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8]
[8, 8, 6, 10, 4, 2, 2]
[10, 4, 4, 0, 16, 6]
[8, 4, 4, 0, 12, 8, 4]
[0, 16, 8, 8, 0, 8]
[4, 0, 8, 4, 6, 4, 0, 6, 0, 16]
[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 0, 16, 6]

{1: [6, 16], 2: [6, 16], 3: [6, 16], 4: [6, 16], 5: [6, 16], 6: [6, 16], 7: [6, 16], 8: [6, 16], 9: [6, 16], 10: [6, 16], 11: [6, 16], 12: [6, 16]}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я косячу?

Comment: значениями словаря являются ссылки на один и тот же список sub_list

Comment: попробуйте что-то в пайтон-стайл, типа week_list = {i: el for i, el in enumerate(array, 1) if sum(el) < 40}

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его галочкой как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

У вас переменная sub_list является значением каждой записи в словаре и ссылается на одно и то же место в памяти...  Попробуйте python style ([1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) [2](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/) [3](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/07/python-style-guide/) и т.д.):

```
array = [
    [16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
    [3, 3, 4, 34],
    [10, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8],
    [4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4],
    [3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 0, 16, 6, 2, 6],
    [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
    [8, 8, 6, 10, 4, 2, 2],
    [10, 4, 4, 0, 16, 6],
    [8, 4, 4, 0, 12, 8, 4],
    [0, 16, 8, 8, 0, 8],
    [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16],
    [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 6]
]
```

"сформировать словарь, где в качестве значений выступают подсписки" можно [представлением словаря](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/08_python_basic_examples/x_comprehensions.html#dict-comprehensions) (не знаю почему, но dict comprehension назван генератором словаря, хотя это разные вещи в python):

```
week_list = {i: el for i, el in enumerate(array, 1) if sum(el) >= 40}
```

в `week_list` будет словарь с порядковым номером списка в исходном `array` в ключах (от 1):

```
>>> week_list
{
    2: [3, 3, 4, 34], 
    5: [3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 0, 16, 6, 2, 6], 
    7: [8, 8, 6, 10, 4, 2, 2], 
    8: [10, 4, 4, 0, 16, 6], 
    9: [8, 4, 4, 0, 12, 8, 4], 
    10: [0, 16, 8, 8, 0, 8]
}
```

или, если ключ должен быть порядковым номером в итоговом `week_list`, то так:

```
index = 0
week_list = dict()

for a in array:
    if sum(a) >= 40:
        week_list.update({index: a})
        index += 1
```

тогда в `week_list` будет:

```
>>> week_list
{
    0: [3, 3, 4, 34], 
    1: [3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 0, 16, 6, 2, 6], 
    2: [8, 8, 6, 10, 4, 2, 2], 
    3: [10, 4, 4, 0, 16, 6], 
    4: [8, 4, 4, 0, 12, 8, 4], 
    5: [0, 16, 8, 8, 0, 8]
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень аккуратный метод, мне зашёл)

Answer (score 1):

```
sub_list.clear()
```

Никогда не используйте метод `list.clear`, если не знаете точно, зачем вы это делаете. Этот метод можно использовать только если у вас используется одна ссылка на этот список. Если же вы хотите именно сделать новый, отдельный список и получить на него ссылку (обычно это делается в каком-то цикле), то нужно это делать стандартным питоновским способом:

```
sub_list = []
```

Это будет уже новый список, не связанный со старым списком.

Comment: сегодня нашел еще такой метод очистки списка `list1 = [1, 2, 3]; list1 *= 0`...

Comment: @Jack_oS забавно )))  но помним, что "явное лучше неявного"

Comment: На такой мелочи споткнулся. Спасибо, максимально полезно!)